# How to plot a Python 3-dimensional level set?

Tags: python, matplotlib, svm

I have some trouble plotting the image which is in my head.
I want to visualize the Kernel-trick with Support Vector Machines. So I made some two-dimensional data consisting of two circles (an inner and an outer circle) which should be separated by a hyperplane. Obviously this isn't possible in two dimensions - so I transformed them into 3D. Let n be the number of samples. Now I have an (n,3)-array (3 columns, n rows) X of data points and an (n,1)-array y with labels. Using sklearn I get the linear classifier via

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1000)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

I already plot the data points as scatter plot via

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=30, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
```

Now I want to plot the separating hyperplane as surface plot. My problem here is the missing explicit representation of the hyperplane because the decision function only yields an implicit hyperplane via `decision_function = 0`. Therefore I need to plot the level set (of level 0) of an 4-dimensional object.

Since I'm not a python expert I would appreciate if somebody could help me out! And I know that this isn't really the "style" of using a SVM but I need this image as an illustration for my thesis.

## Edit: my current "code"

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs, make_circles

from tikzplotlib import save as tikz_save

plt.close('all')

# we create 50 separable points
#X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=40, centers=2, random_state=6)
X,  y  = make_circles(n_samples=50, factor=0.5, random_state=4, noise=.05)
X2, y2 = make_circles(n_samples=50, factor=0.2, random_state=5, noise=.08)

X = np.append(X,X2, axis=0)
y = np.append(y,y2, axis=0)

# shifte X to [0,2]x[0,2]
X = np.array([[item[0] + 1, item[1] + 1] for item in X])
X[X<0] = 0.01

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1000)
clf.fit(X, y)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=30, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)


# plot the decision function
ax = plt.gca()
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

# create grid to evaluate model
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 30)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 30)
YY, XX = np.meshgrid(yy, xx)
xy = np.vstack([XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()]).T
Z = clf.decision_function(xy).reshape(XX.shape)

# plot decision boundary and margins
ax.contour(XX, YY, Z, colors='k', levels=[-1, 0, 1], alpha=0.5, linestyles=['--','-','--'])
# plot support vectors
ax.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1], s=100,
           linewidth=1, facecolors='none', edgecolors='k')


################## KERNEL TRICK - 3D ##################

trans_X = np.array([[item[0]**2, item[1]**2, np.sqrt(2*item[0]*item[1])] for item in X])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")
 
# creating scatter plot
ax.scatter3D(trans_X[:,0],trans_X[:,1],trans_X[:,2], c = y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

clf2 = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1000)
clf2.fit(trans_X, y)


ax = plt.gca(projection='3d')
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
zlim = ax.get_zlim()

### from here i don't know what to do ###
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 3)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 3)
zz = np.linspace(zlim[0], zlim[1], 3)
ZZ, YY, XX = np.meshgrid(zz, yy, xx)
xyz = np.vstack([XX.ravel(), YY.ravel(), ZZ.ravel()]).T
Z = clf2.decision_function(xyz).reshape(XX.shape)
#ax.contour(XX, YY, ZZ, Z, colors='k', levels=[-1, 0, 1], alpha=0.5, linestyles=['--','-','--'])
```

## Desired Output

I want to get something like [that](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*zWzeMGyCc7KvGD9X8lwlnQ.png).
In general I want to reconstruct what they do in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-kernel-trick-c98cdbcaeb3f), especially "Non-linear transformations".

Comment: Can you share your data and desired output to provide an ['minimal, reproducible example'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I edited my post - I hope this is going to help. I know that it is not really minimal, however maybe it's easier to understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Part of your question is addressed in [this question on linear-kernel SVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232334/plotting-3d-decision-boundary-from-linear-svm/36237873#36237873). It's a partial answer, because only linear kernels can be represented this way, i.e. thanks to hyperplane coordinates accessible via the estimator when using linear kernel.

### Another solution is to find the isosurface with `marching_cubes`

This solution involves installing the `scikit-image` toolkit (https://scikit-image.org) which allows to find an isosurface of a given value (here, I considered 0 since it represents the distance to the hyperplane) from the mesh grid of the 3D coordinates.

In the code below (copied from yours), I implement the idea for any kernel (in the example, I used the RBF kernel), and the output is shown beneath the code. Please consider my footnote about 3D plotting with matplotlib, which may be another issue in your case.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from skimage import measure
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs, make_circles

from tikzplotlib import save as tikz_save
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

plt.close('all')

# we create 50 separable points
#X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=40, centers=2, random_state=6)
X,  y  = make_circles(n_samples=50, factor=0.5, random_state=4, noise=.05)
X2, y2 = make_circles(n_samples=50, factor=0.2, random_state=5, noise=.08)

X = np.append(X,X2, axis=0)
y = np.append(y,y2, axis=0)

# shifte X to [0,2]x[0,2]
X = np.array([[item[0] + 1, item[1] + 1] for item in X])
X[X<0] = 0.01

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1000)
clf.fit(X, y)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=30, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)


# plot the decision function
ax = plt.gca()
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

# create grid to evaluate model
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 30)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 30)
YY, XX = np.meshgrid(yy, xx)
xy = np.vstack([XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()]).T
Z = clf.decision_function(xy).reshape(XX.shape)

# plot decision boundary and margins
ax.contour(XX, YY, Z, colors='k', levels=[-1, 0, 1], alpha=0.5, linestyles=['--','-','--'])
# plot support vectors
ax.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1], s=100,
           linewidth=1, facecolors='none', edgecolors='k')


################## KERNEL TRICK - 3D ##################

trans_X = np.array([[item[0]**2, item[1]**2, np.sqrt(2*item[0]*item[1])] for item in X])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")

# creating scatter plot
ax.scatter3D(trans_X[:,0],trans_X[:,1],trans_X[:,2], c = y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

clf2 = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1000)
clf2.fit(trans_X, y)


z = lambda x,y: (-clf2.intercept_[0]-clf2.coef_[0][0]*x-clf2.coef_[0][1]*y) / clf2.coef_[0][2]

ax = plt.gca(projection='3d')
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
zlim = ax.get_zlim()

### from here i don't know what to do ###
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 50)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 50)
zz = np.linspace(zlim[0], zlim[1], 50)
XX ,YY, ZZ = np.meshgrid(xx, yy, zz)
xyz = np.vstack([XX.ravel(), YY.ravel(), ZZ.ravel()]).T
Z = clf2.decision_function(xyz).reshape(XX.shape)

# find isosurface with marching cubes
dx = xx[1] - xx[0]
dy = yy[1] - yy[0]
dz = zz[1] - zz[0]
verts, faces, _, _ = measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(Z, 0, spacing=(1, 1, 1), step_size=2)
verts *= np.array([dx, dy, dz])
verts -= np.array([xlim[0], ylim[0], zlim[0]])

# add as Poly3DCollection
mesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces])
mesh.set_facecolor('g')
mesh.set_edgecolor('none')
mesh.set_alpha(0.3)
ax.add_collection3d(mesh)
ax.view_init(20, -45)
plt.savefig('kerneltrick')
```

Running the code produces the following image with Matplotlib, where the green semi-transparent surface represents the non-linear decision boundary.

[image: SVM with RBF kernel in 3D]

### Footnote: 3D plotting with matplotlib

Note that Matplotlib 3D is not able to manage the "depth" of objects in some cases, because it can be in conflict with the `zorder` of this object. This is the reason why sometimes the hyperplane look to be plotted "on top of" the points, even it should be "behind". This issue is a known bug discussed in [the matplotlib 3d documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64052839/5405298).

If you want to have better rendering results, you may want to use [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/), as recommended by the Matplotlib developers, or any other 3D Python plotting library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and this answer! Just one more question: is it an optical illusion that every time some data point seem to lie on the wrong side? I set the transparency to None but in my optinion there are points on the wrong side.

Comment: Considering the footnote and that the decision boundary can also be imperfect: some points may lie on the wrong side of the boundary but it can be a bad optical illusion due Matplotlib 3D rendering (see the footnote of my answer).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - know I have understood your footnote. Thank you very much :)